# How can I map a hostname to localhost with only port?

Tags: web-hosting, host

I want to map `dev.website.com:8300` to `localhost:8080`, but any other ports like `dev.website.com:xxx` still map to remote `dev.website.com` server.

How can I achieve it by a simple way?

Comment: Is it a server running in 8080, are you using a web server behind the domain?

Comment: @armourshield Yes, it is running on my computer. I want to do some local debug.

Comment: Instead of porting the server (localhost:8080) to (dev.website.com:8300), you can proxy pass it as subdomain something like dev.website.com/server. You can debug from there.

Comment: What is running in localhost:8080, as you may need to change config there for subdomain and what web server are you using?